# Convert Random Forest from Julia to R

Tags: r, julia, random-forest, converters

I am currently learning Random Forests (RF) with a dataset of 500 000 examples and 6 features. However, it takes hours in R. Thus, my idea would be to use an other language to learn the RF. I was thinking about Julia. However, I found R more convenient for predictions and all the *post hoc* analysis. Then, my question is very simple:

**Is there a way to convert a RF from the Julia format to R?**

Comment: The "ju" in [Jupyter notebook](https://blog.jupyter.org/i-python-you-r-we-julia-baf064ca1fb6) comes from Julia and the er at the end refers to R. I suspect you could do the whole analysis on a Jupyter notebook? There's also an option to do it in [Rmarkdown](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/JuliaCall/vignettes/Julia_in_RMarkdown.html)

Comment: Ho, that would be a smart move. The problem is that, for me, you need to set the kernel for your script so when you use Julia in Jupyter, you are actually using Julia and can't cross the languages

Comment: the blog post I shared claims it is possible to start Julia and Python together... I presumed it would be possible to use R as well. If not, then the Rmarkdown option should work.

Comment: I'm a Julia user (former R user), but I have to admit that the [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/index.html) R package is at least as fast as (and possibly faster than) [DecisionTree.jl](https://github.com/bensadeghi/DecisionTree.jl), and is also more memory efficient.

Comment: @Cameron The R package you linked is mostly C++... The nice of Julia is that packages are almost all wrote in Julia itself, so easier to dirty your hands in..

Answer (score 2):

Within Julia you could use RCall to write the code for post hoc, while running the ML itself in Julia, perhaps? You can create your Julia data frames and then do '@rput df' to put the dataframe into the R space, and get back values with '@rget val'. Lines of R code are run inside Julia.

```
using Dataframes, RCall, CSV   
#create Julia dataframe, however you choose
df = CSV.read("path/to/my/data", header=false) 
@rput df
R"""
lines of R code here to work with df
"""
@rget myvalues
```

Comment: Very good idea! On my side, I found the [JuliaConnectoR](https://github.com/stefan-m-lenz/JuliaConnectoR) package which does the opposite: using Julia directly in R. I don't know which solution would be the most efficient though

Answer (score 0):

I started by using the [JuliaConnectoR](https://github.com/stefan-m-lenz/JuliaConnectoR) package, which is really awesome and efficient. I dropped from more than 1 hour of learning with the [randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package to **3 or 6 seconds** with JuliaConnectoR.

Then, I followed @Cameron's advice with the [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package. The performance are also pretty good (~ 9 seconds).